# Different Colour Scatter points without using Hold on (or all)

Tags: matlab, colors, matlab-figure, scatter-plot, scatter

I would like to create a scatter plot in MATLAB using three sets of data. `X`,`Y` and `c`. `X` and `Y` are to be their respective axis plots but `c` holds information (integer values) on each scatter points classification. I wish to make each classification plot as a separate colour. These integer values are simple enough to convert into respective colour choices so no problem there.
Currently, with `C` as my colour choice, I am using,

```
    hold on
for k=1:K
    scatter(X(c==k,:),Y(c==k),[],C(k,:),'filled');
end
```

My motivation for this is that I wish to create an `UpdateFcn` in `DataCursorManager` in order to show the dates of each point with the data cursor. I have been unable to do this with the multiple scatter plots and figure this is the simplest way about the problem.

Comment: Scatter supports 4 input arguments as, scatter(x,y,a,c), where in c you can specify the color for all the points without iteratively plotting each. You may visit http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html for more information. Please provide a sample data if you want to see how to do it.

Comment: where is the date information you want in the datatip ... in `X`, `Y`, or in another variable ?

Comment: Yes @Hwathanie. I failed to realise that the `c` in `scatter` could be a matrix as opposed to a `1x3` vector. This is all working correctly. Thank you.

Comment: As you have guessed (in your answer) @Hoki the date data is a separate vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As told in the comment, `scatter` can take a 4th argument which will represent the color. The 3rd argument (the one you use with `c` for each of your scatter plot), only controls the size.

For you, the way to call `scatter` should be:
`scatter(x,y, size, colour , 'filled')`

Read well the [documentation for `scatter`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) to understand its usage better.

Below is a quick example on how to use it with 4 parameters. I had to create sample data since you didn't specify any (I chose to have dates in the `x` axis, and I assumed you wanted the same size for all the groups ... but adjust that to your needs).

Note that the scatter object has a property named `CData`. This is the same size of `x` and it contains the colour for each data point (well the index of the colour in the figure colormap). This is what we use to know the classification of your point in the datatip function. You can directly readjust this `CData` vector if you want to change the colour interactively.

```
function h = scatter_datatip_demo

%// basic sample data
npts = 50 ;
nClass = 12 ; %// let's say we have 12 different class
x = round(now) + randi([-10 10],npts,1) ;
y = rand(size(x)) ;
s = ones(size(x))*40 ;
c = randi([1 nClass],size(x)); %// randomly assign a class for each point

%// Draw a single scatter plot (specifying the colour as the 4th input)
h.f = figure ;
h.p = scatter(x,y , s , c , 'filled') ; %// <== Note how scatter is called
colormap( jet(nClass) ) ;

%// add custom datatip function
set( datacursormode(h.f) , 'UpdateFcn',@customDatatipFunction );


function output_txt = customDatatipFunction(~,evt)
    pos = get(evt,'Position');

    hp = handle( get(evt,'Target') ) ;           %// get the handle of the scatter plot object
    ptClass = hp.CData( get(evt,'DataIndex') ) ; %// get the colour index of the current point

    output_txt = { ...
        'My custom datatip' , ...
        ['Date : ' , datestr(pos(1))  ] ...
        ['Class: ' , num2str(ptClass) ] ...
        ['Value: ' , num2str(pos(2),8)] ...
                };
```

[image: demoimg]

Comment: Wow, thank you @Hoki. That worked perfectly. I was trying for a good few hours to get to this point. Could explain something though? Why do you use the ~ in customDatatipFunction(~,evt)?

Comment: @josh, the `~` operator in place of an argument indicates to the compiler that you will not use this argument (so the m-lint will not complain later that you do not use it). In most callback functions the first parameter is usually the handle of the caller object, often useful, but in the case of the `datatip` this is always empty, so really no need to assign it to a variable. So the `~` just says "ignore that". You can read [this article](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/01/11/about-the-unused-argument-syntax-in-r2009b/) for more details.

Comment: @josh, actually, [this article](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/09/11/matlab-release-2009b-best-new-feature-or/) is the initial one (the link I gave above is just a follow-up).

Comment: Ok. I tried to change it so that the date stamp is not the X variable but I have had no luck with this. It is partially because I do not know what the `evt` refers to in the function `@customDatatipFunction(~,evt)`. My date info is stored in `date`. Thanks

Comment: Right, so. I've now figured it out to some extant by setting the `ZData=datenum(date)` (as my `date` was a datetime) to my respective date values. I then used datestr(pos(3)) to show the date in the data-cursor box.

Comment: Final post: I now use `UserData` instead of `ZData` so that I have `UData=hp.UserData(get(evt,'DataIndex'));` and then `datestr(UData)`. I guess this is a clear more general version as it can then be used along with scatter3.

Comment: @josh. Well done. `userdata` is one way to do it and it's clean enough. If it gives you trouble look at `setappdata` and `getappdata` ([documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html)). The `evt` refers to the `eventdata` object returned by the `datatip`. If you put a breakpoint in debug mode you can see it contains the current position and the dataindex.